# How to call AJAX callback to upload a file?

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, oracle-apex

i am trying to upload a file through ajax callback (array buffer) and it's working fine when file size is around 6MB, but when file size around 10MB this error appear

> POST http://localhost:90/ords/wwv_flow.ajax 500

I am trying the by below code :-

```js
  apex.server.process(
      'UPLOAD_FILE',
      {
        x01: "test",
        x02: "application/pdf",
        f01: f01Array
      },
      {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           if (data.result == 'success') {
           // apex.event.trigger( "#CLD", "apexrefresh" );
           
            apex.submit( 'APPROVE' );               
           }
               else {
                     alert('Oops! Something went terribly wrong. Please try again or contact your application administrator.');
               }
                
           }
        }
      
    );
```

the f01Array meaning  the file .
The below code for ajax callback

```sql
declare
  l_blob blob;
  l_filename varchar2(200);
  l_mime_type varchar2(200);
  l_token varchar2(32000);

begin 
  l_filename := apex_application.g_x01;
  l_mime_type := apex_application.g_x02;
 
  -- build BLOB from f01 30k array (base64 encoded)
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_blob, false, dbms_lob.session);
  for i in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count loop
    l_token := wwv_flow.g_f01(i);
    if length(l_token) > 0 then
      dbms_lob.append(
        dest_lob => l_blob,
        src_lob => to_blob(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_token)))
      );
    end if;
  end loop;
 
  -- add collection member (only if BLOB is not null)
  if dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob) is not null then
    apex_collection.add_member(
      p_collection_name => 'UPLOADED_FILES',
      p_c001 => l_filename,
      p_c002 => l_mime_type,
      p_blob001 => l_blob
    );
  end if;
 
  apex_json.open_object;
  apex_json.write(
    p_name => 'result',
    p_value => 'success'
  );
  apex_json.close_object;
exception
  when others then
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write(
      p_name => 'result',
      p_value => 'fail'
    );
    apex_json.close_object;
end;
```

Environment

```
apex version 19.2 
tomcat 8.5 ,
ords
```

Comment: 500 just means a server error, and sounds like the file is too large? The issue is on the server side, not the POST. What server is it? What is the code? Where is the 500 coming from?

Comment: not server my laptop only , and the error come from the "apex.server.process" and appear in console ,  now you can see the ajax callback code in question